# I get this error: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined at String.toJadenCase

Tags: javascript, regex, string, uppercase

```
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function (str) {
  //...
 var capitalize = str; 

 return capitalize.replace(/^[a-zA-Z]*$/, function(txt){
     return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
}
```

When I pass the string "How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real" as a parameter I get the error. It should return each word capitalized like: "How Can Mirrors Be Real If Our Eyes Aren't Real".

I am new to JS and programming in general, so this could be trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `toJadenCase` method is running within the context of the `String`, so use the `this` keyword to retrieve the text. You'll also need to fiddle with your regex a bit:

```js
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function () {
        return this.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
}

var copy = "How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real";

alert(copy.toJadenCase());
```

Note that this gracefully handles your comma.

Answer (score 0):

Since your function is expecting a parameter, the way to call it would be:

```
myStr.toJadenCase(myStr);
```

which is not what you want.

But, if you use `this` instead, it will work:

```
return this.replace(/^[a-zA-Z]*$/, function(txt){
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
});
```

(this gets rid of the error, but your case changing code is not working as expected)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` without the need for the parameter. The Regex `\b` matches character at word boundaries.

```
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function () {
    return this.replace(/\b./g, function(m){ 
        return m.toUpperCase();    
    });
}
```

The regex doesn't take care of special case as `aren't`. You have to match a space followed by a character. For that you can instead use

```
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function () {
    return this.replace(/\s./g, function(m){ 
        return m.toUpperCase();    
    });
}
```

Or to be more specific you can use `/\s[a-zA-Z]/g`.

You can see the regex in action [here](http://regexr.com/3a9gq).

**Usage**

```
str = "How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real";
console.log(str.toJadenCase());
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to have it use `this`, and also, your regex is wrong.

```
function () {

 return this.replace(/\b[a-zA-Z]*\b/g, function(txt){
     return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
}
```

I changed the regex to use word separators, and be global.